# How to get the list of images in the application folder wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path

I want to get the image list in the image folder in the application folder. The following code will returns the Images in the Mypicture folder.

```
 string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
```

Geetha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: Run your WPF application in Adminstrator mode, you can access to any folders.

Comment: If your application set Images as BuidAction:Content & Copy to OutputDirectory:Copy if newer, then those images will be copied to D:/App/bin/Debug/Images/Banner. By Default BuildAction will be Resource.

Comment: Can you check whether the images are created in D:/App/bin/Debug/Images/Banner folder?

Comment: You should set Build Action to each & every image, then only it will copy to output folder. 
http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/resources-in-wpf-i-binary-resources/ 

Have u tried as below code to get images string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Images\Banner");

Comment: Yes. But it gave folder not found so i have removed the bin name.All the have build action = Resource

Comment: I am not clear whether the images are created  in D:/App/bin/Debug/Images/Banner folder? This should be created at compile time.

Comment: base directory only have exe and pdb files

Comment: I have created like right click add folder + Images. Inside that folder Banner folder  + right click add existing items ( Added the images).

Comment: Make sure the Images/Banner is included in your project and each image propertiens inside the folder should set to BuildAction:'Content' & OutputDirectory:'Copy if newer'. Then those images will be added the Output directory.

Comment: Pls read the following articles to know more.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx

http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/resources-in-wpf-i-binary-resources/